# GNU Scientific Library probability distribution functions in C

Tags: c, histogram, structure, gsl

I have a set of GSL Histograms, which are used to make a set of probability distribution functions, which according to the documentation are stored in a struct, as follows:

```
Data Type: gsl_histogram_pdf

    size_t n
        This is the number of bins used to approximate the probability distribution function.
    double * range
        The ranges of the bins are stored in an array of n+1 elements pointed to by range.
    double * sum
        The cumulative probability for the bins is stored in an array of n elements pointed to by sum.
```

I am intending to use a KS test to determine, if data was similar or not. So, I am trying to access the sum of a given bin in this structure, to calculate the 'distance' and I assumed that, I should be able to access that value by using:

```
((my_type)->pdf->sum+x)
```

with X being the bin number.

Yet this always returns 0 no matter what I do, does anyone have any idea, what is going wrong?

Thanks in advance

---- EDIT ----

Here is a snippet of my code that deals with the pdf / histogram:

```
   /* GSL Histogram creation */
   for (i = 0; i < chrom->hits; i++) {
       if ( (chrom+i)->spectra->peaks != 0 ) {
           (chrom+i)->hist = gsl_histogram_alloc(bins);
           gsl_histogram_set_ranges_uniform((chrom+i)->hist, low_mz, high_mz);
           for (j = 0; j < (chrom+i)->spectra->peaks; j++) {
               gsl_histogram_increment( (chrom+i)->hist, ((chrom+i)->spectra+j)->mz_value);
           }
       } else {
           printf("0 value encountered!\n");
       }
   }
   /* Histogram probability distribution function creation */
   for (i = 0; i < chrom->hits; i++) {
       if ( (chrom+i)->spectra->peaks != 0 ) {
           (chrom+i)->pdf = gsl_histogram_pdf_alloc(bins);
           gsl_histogram_pdf_init( (chrom+i)->pdf, (chrom+i)->hist);
       } else {
           continue;
       }
   } 
   /* Kolmogorov-Smirnov */
   float D;
   for (i = 0; i < chrom->hits-1; i++) {
       printf("%f\n",((chrom+i)->pdf->sum+25));
       for (j = i+1; j < chrom->hits; j++) {
           D = 0;
           diff = 0;
           /* Determine max distance */
       }
   }
```

Comment: I thought so as well but it never contains a value and as far as I know the only way to test if the PDF is made in the first place is using "gsl_histogram_pdf_sample" function which does return values...

Comment: Did you try gsl_histogram_pdf_alloc() and the gsl_histogram_pdf_init() before accessing the above variable?

Comment: I did, i'll post the entire snippet that I have now in the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compute a *pointer* to the value you intend to access.

Change your current pointer computation

```
printf("%f\n",((chrom+i)->pdf->sum+25));
```

either to a normal array subscript

```
printf("%f\n",(chrom+i)->pdf->sum[25]);
```

or to a pointer computation followed by a dereferencing

```
printf("%f\n",*((chrom+i)->pdf->sum+25));
```

See whether that fixes your issue. The value shouldn't be 0 either, but it might well get *displayed* as 0 as it might represent a pretty small floating point number, depending on memory virtual layout.

Comment: Mvg, thanks for your time first off ;) The *((chrom+i)->pdf->sum+25) notation doesn't work but I did also notice that (chrom+i)->pdf->sum[25] did work and I'm not really sure why as I don't really understand the difference :(

Comment: @BasJansen, I'm surprised, as the two should result in identical code. It would be interestint to see a minimal self-contained example and have a look at the assembly code for both alternatives. But as long as there is a working version, using that should be fine.